# Get custom attribute to transasctional email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail

I am trying to retrieve a customer attribute in a transactional mail. In my editor at the back-office, I put `{{var request.getCustomAttribute ()}`, but it doesn't work. What is the method to retrieve the custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check *'who'* sends the email template and see which are the parameters sent to the template, so that you can grasp the way you can call your attribute by either accessing the existing customer object or sending your custom object or parameter.

I suggest you check the class `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` and method `confirmationAction()` where the `sendNewAccountEmail()` is used.

Go to the definition of the method and back the line to the protected method `_sendEmailTemplate()` of the `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` class. there you will see that an array of *template parameters* are sent and made available in the confirmation mail template which is `account_new_confirmation.html`. Check how the parameters sent down the line are used.

I hope this will help you understand the underlining mechanism of using parameters in transactional emails. Good Luck!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I am still a beginner on Magento (I'm in traineeship) , I will follow your solution :)

Comment: hi there, any luck?